# how to log to file using an Apache C module

Tags: c++, c, apache

I am new to Apache module development and I saw that there is this function for my needs:

```
ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_ERR, r->server,"some error");
```

anyway I dont know how to create the third parameter which is supposed to be a server_rec struct.

I am calling it from my:

```
static int example_handler(request_rec *r)
{
...
}
```

and **request_rec->server** contains such struct but I am getting a warning

```
warning: passing argument 5 of 'ap_log_error_' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_ERR, r->server,"some error");
```

and then this:

```
/usr/include/apache2/http_log.h:372:18: note: expected 'apr_status_t {aka int}' but argument is of type 'server_rec * {aka struct server_rec *}'
 AP_DECLARE(void) ap_log_error_(const char *file, int line, int module_index,
                  ^
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

how shall I call it to finally log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had luck using a different logging call, `ap_log_rerror`

So something like this:

```
void someFunc(request_rec *r) {
    ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_DEBUG, APR_SUCCESS, r,
                  " Error msg!");`
}
```